# Example projects for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, demo

I am looking for a very small web application built especially to demonstrate jQuery library. In Java world 'Appfuse' for example is built especially to demonstrate how various frameworks  can be used and it uses some example use cases such as 'Search Users,'Add Users' etc

ThemeRoller and Other jQuery websites demonstrate individual widgets but I am looking for a complete web application especially built to demonstrate the complete jQuery world.

Here is the purpose of Appfuse:
AppFuse is an open source project and application that uses open source tools built on the Java platform to help you develop Web applications quickly and efficiently. It was originally developed to eliminate the ramp-up time found when building new web applications for customers. At its core, AppFuse is a project skeleton, similar to the one that's created by your IDE when you click through a wizard to create a new web project.

I am looking something like this for jQuery with any platform (Rails or Django or php)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those functions are documented all over the internet (http://jqueryui.com/demos/). What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Introduction to Complex UIs Using jQuery UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/hh127352)

The above article does not cover the back end nor is it a project framework, but I think it's close to what you're asking for when you say "*... demonstrate how various frameworks can be used and it uses some example use cases such as 'Search Users,'Add Users' etc*"

Comment: You are the man, yep, this is goo enough for me to quick start. Great!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like the jQuery UI Demos page?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Comment: No, not this. I am looking for a very small web application built especially to demonstrate jQuery library. Appfuse for example is built especially to demonstrate how various frameworks can be used and it uses some example use cases such as 'Search Users,'Add Users' etc.

Comment: You will need to be more specific. There are endless examples/tutorials on getting started with jQuery or jQuery UI. What technology are you using it with? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Here is the example purpose of Appfuse but this geared towards Java based projects: "AppFuse is an open source project and application that uses open source tools built on the Java platform to help you develop Web applications quickly and efficiently. It was originally developed to eliminate the ramp-up time found when building new web applications for customers. At its core, AppFuse is a project skeleton, similar to the one that's created by your IDE when you click through a wizard to create a new web project." I am looking a similar project for jQuery.

Comment: I think the problem is the above does not translate to jQuery specifically. Do you have a list of other technologies you want to use with it? Like, an example of jQuery with ASP.NET MVC, or how to make a CRUD table with jQuery UI and PHP. jQuery is just a javascript framework. Rethink what you are trying to ask/find.